# busybox passwd script run failed

Tags: shell, busybox, passwd

busybox passwd can't use --stdin option, when i excute passwd,it need to input password twice,
i want to write a shell script to change auto because some reason.
i do passwd manual，it works fine。
`your text`but when i write a script like this

```
#!/bin/sh
passwd << EOF
<new password>
<new password>
EOF
```

when i sh this script,the result is `password for root is unchanged.`
is there some wrong,i am a shell rookie,hope someone can help me,thank you!

i want sh script success!

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible you just need to add a line with the current pass,
**THIS IS VERY DANGEROUS** especially for the root user.

the script would look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
passwd << EOF
<current pass>
<new pass>
<new pass>
EOF
```

there is probably a much safer methode to do the thing you want to do,
feel free to send me a message.

Comment: thank you for your reply, the script your answed i also tried,the result is failed as same,and when i type passwd in shell,it only let me input new pass。

Comment: i try this script in another machine,the command passwd also busybox.it works fine. i think the problem is the Embedded system self。